# What is the time complexity of this algorithm where the limit is changing inside the loop?

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o

How do you calculate the time complexity or big-O of this algorithm, where it is not clear how many iterations the loop iterates?

```
cin >> n;
int i = 0;
for (int j=1; i <= n; j++) {
    i += j;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appreciate that the series in `j` looks like this:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n (not the n in your question)
```

The *sum* of this series is given by the Gaussian formula:

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

This means that the sum varies as `n^2`, where `n` is the number of terms or steps in the loop.  Therefore, the loop should vary as:

```
O(sqrt(n))
```

Where now `n` here is the `n` from your loop code, i.e. the upper bound of the loop.